# Reaching flood victims for a survey

Tags: usa, survey, geohazard

I want to send a small set of survey questions to recent flood victims in the US.
- Where do I start in order to get a mailing list?
- Are there organizations that will forward the survey link to the victims' emails (or phones/social media accounts, etc.) even though they may not share the contact information with me?

Comment: A comment: if this is for academic research you probably need to get approval for research on human subjects, even if the questions seem benign. You could try the Red Cross or city government

Comment: If you can get geospatial data of the flood extent, you can intersect it with property data and send a bulk mailer to all the property addresses. Of course flood-damaged properties may not be occupied.